# '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, Map<String, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dy namic>' of 'other'

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been getting this weird exception which is

'_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, Map<String, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' of 'other'.

I dont know how Map<String, dynamic>> is not subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>>

The first time I run the code it works fine as it access the else part. The second time when it should access the first part it produces the above exception.

```
Future addMeal(meal,mealName,date,cal,protein,carbs,fats) async{
 List<dynamic> foodLog= List<dynamic>();

 Map <String,dynamic> temp = Map();


await users.document(user.uid).get().then((doc) {
  foodLog = doc.data['foodLog'];
  int i = 0;
  while(i<=foodLog.length-1) {
    if (foodLog[i].containsKey(date)) {
      temp = foodLog[i];

      temp['$date']['$meal'].addAll({
        mealName:{'cal':cal,'protein':protein,'carbs':carbs,'fats':fats}

      });

      foodLog[i] = temp;
      break;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  if(i==foodLog.length){
    temp = {'$date':{'Breakfast':{},'Dinner':{},'Lunch':{},'Snacks':{}}};
    temp['$date']['$meal'].addAll({
     mealName:{'cal':cal,'protein':protein,'carbs':carbs,'fats':fats}
   });
  }
});
foodLog.add(temp);
print(foodLog);
return await users.document(user.uid).updateData({
  'foodLog':foodLog
});
```

}

**OUTPUT**

FoodLog output:

{Aug 3, 2021: {Breakfast: {Fish Filet: {carbs: 0.0, fats: 1.7, protein: 20.08, cal: 95}}, Dinner: {}, Snacks: {}, Lunch: {}}}

E/flutter ( 6596): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, Map<String, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dy
namic>' of 'other'

Comment: Hi Saeed, In which line is the error happening?

Comment: Hi George,               temp['$date']['$meal'].addAll({
        mealName:{'cal':cal,'protein':protein,'carbs':carbs,'fats':fats}

      });

Comment: are you using `null-safety`? Make empty list like `List<dynamic> foodLog=  [];` or you can make it nullable by `List<dynamic>? foodLog`

Comment: No I am not using null safety, and I didn't upgrade yet

Comment: Can you provide your output?

Comment: I added the output

Comment: I mean the content of `foodLog `

Comment: I added the content

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct content? Because the value `Aug 3` has no key

Comment: This can't be a valid json response

Comment: AH nvm I got it. The first key is `Aug 3, 2021`

Comment: Aug 3, should be the initial key

Comment: Not `Aug 3,  2021`?

Comment: Aug 3,  2021 is the key

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to cast your item to a `Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>`. Then it should work.

```
temp['$date']['$meal'].addAll({
     mealName:{'cal':cal,'protein':protein,'carbs':carbs,'fats':fats}
   } as Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>);
```